# clang fails on linking the 2 line main function program

Tags: c++, linker, clang

I apt-get-ed the clang and this is what happens when I try to compile simple 2 line program:
( I have g++ on the machine, IDK if that is the cause of the problem)

> clang   teststring.cpp -v Ubuntu clang version 3.0-6ubuntu3
>   (tags/RELEASE_30/final) (based on LLVM 3.0) Target: i386-pc-linux-gnu
>   Thread model: posix  "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple i386-pc-linux-gnu
>   -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name teststring.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu pentium4 -target-linker-version 2.22 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v
>   -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.0 -fmodule-cache-path /var/tmp/clang-module-cache -internal-isystem /usr/include/c++/4.6
>   -internal-isystem /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.0/include
>   -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/i686-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -fgnu-runtime -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-fragile-abi -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /tmp/teststring-e3FNx4.o -x c++ teststring.cpp clang -cc1 version 3.0 based upon llvm 3.0 hosted on i386-pc-linux-gnu
>   ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/i686-linux-gnu" ignoring
>   nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.6//i686-linux-gnu/32"
>   ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/i686-linux-gnu/" ignoring
>   nonexistent directory "/usr/include/i686-linux-gnu" ignoring duplicate
>   directory "/usr/include/c++/4.6" ignoring duplicate directory
>   "/usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu" ignoring duplicate directory
>   "/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward" ignoring duplicate directory
>   "/usr/include/c++/4.6" ignoring duplicate directory
>   "/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward" ignoring duplicate directory
>   "/usr/include/c++/4.6" ignoring duplicate directory
>   "/usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu" ignoring duplicate directory
>   "/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward" ignoring duplicate directory
>   "/usr/local/include" ignoring duplicate directory
>   "/usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.0/include" ignoring duplicate directory
>   "/usr/include"
>   include "..." search starts here: 
>   include <...> search starts here:  /usr/include/c++/4.6  /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu  /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward
>   /usr/local/include  /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.0/include  /usr/include
>   /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/  /usr/include/clang/3.0/include/ 
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include/
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed/ End of search list.
>   "/usr/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --as-needed --build-id 
>   --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o a.out /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o 
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o 
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o 
>   -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu -L/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../.. -L/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib /tmp/teststring-e3FNx4.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o
>   /tmp/teststring-e3FNx4.o: In function `main':
>
>   teststring.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to`
>   std::basic_string, std::allocator
>
> > ::basic_string()' teststring.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `std::string::operator+=(char const*)' teststring.cpp:(.text+0x3e):
> >     undefined reference to`std::basic_string, std::allocator >::~basic_string()'
> >     teststring.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to
> >     `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
> >     ::~basic_string()' teststring.cpp:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to`std::terminate()' /tmp/teststring-e3FNx4.o:(.eh_frame+0x13):
> >     undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0' clang: error: linker
> >     command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

P.S. for curious program is :

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
        std::string s;
        s+="banana";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is C++ code, so try using `clang++` instead of `clang` so that the C++ standard library is linked.

Comment: wow... I cant believe I didnt know this... is this recent... I vaguely remember running clang without ++ on cpp sources.

Comment: You can do that if you manually link to the C++ standard library with `-lstdc++` (or `-lc++` for libc++). It's the same with `gcc` and `g++`.